# Is there a way on forcing the browser to auto reload whenever there is a new build using VueJS in production?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a mobile app which is only a web view of the VueJS web app. I want the browser to auto-reload the page whenever it detects that a new build is built. Is there something like this?

I know that the assets are "hashed", so I am thinking of checking the hash change and do a reload, but where would I do that?

Comment: Don't think you can do it from a front end side. If it can be done probably from a server side.

Comment: I mean, maybe in some hooks before or after build, I can do some checks and trigger a reload. Someone find something in Angular: https://blog.nodeswat.com/automagic-reload-for-clients-after-deploy-with-angular-4-8440c9fdd96c